# Symfony form: customize the setter that is called

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a Symfony form custom type for an entity.

I want to customize the code that is executed when the form is submitted, but only for a field.

For example, Symfony will by default call this:

```
$entity->setFoo($value);
```

I want to do call instead something like:

```
$entity->doSomething($value, true);
```

How can I do that without affecting all other properties that are correctly mapped with the form?

Comment: Symfony calls $entity->set{$someThing) = $someThing , isn't it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define your `foo` field in the form as `not mapped` and then add listener on the `POST_SUBMIT` that will call your `doSomething()` method:

```
$builder->add('foo', null, array('mapped' => false))
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) {
            $entity = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $entity->doSomething($event->getForm()->get('foo')->getData(), true);
        }
    );
```

It will not call `$entity->setFoo($value)`. Instead it will call `$entity->doSomething($value, true)` as you wished.

Comment: Great workaround, but entity validation and maybe some other stuffs  will not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://webmozart.io/blog/2015/09/09/value-objects-in-symfony-forms/#data-mappers) post about DataMapper (it starts from explaining Value Objects, but link will scroll down to `Data Mappers` header directly). It's very useful but missed in Symfony docs.