# Passing a parameter to Symfony's FormBuilder add()

Tags: forms, symfony, formbuilder

I'm trying to display a form that contains all `Question`s in `Survey` x, with the `Answer` data from `User` y. The classes have these relations:

- `User` m-m `Survey`
- `Survey` 1-m `Question`
- `Question` 1-m `Answer`
- `User` 1-m `Answer`

Question objects normally hold a collection of all Answers. I *thought* I was being cunning by creating a method on Question which would return an Answer for a specific User:

```
class Question
{
    public function getAnswer(User $user)
    {
        return $this->getAnswers()->filter(function(Answer $answer) use ($user) {
            return $answer->getUserId() == $user->getId();
        })->first();
    }
}
```

Ignoring the shonky eager-loaded `filter()` call for a second; I'm at a loss as to how I should tie this into Symfony's FormBuilder:

The Survey form:

```
class SurveyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('questions', 'collection', ['type' => new QuestionType()]);
    }
}
```

The Question form:

```
class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user  $user;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // How to pass $this->user to the FormBuilder's call to $question->getAnswer()?
        $builder->add('answer', 'text');
    }
}
```

The problem is that the framework tries to populate the field's data by calling `$question->getAnswer()`, which fails because it requires a User param. Is there a way of passing that parameter in? Or should I be approaching this problem from a completely different angle?

Comment: I think you would be better off getting the user based answers when you query for questions.  However, you could pass the user to the constructor of the form type.  new QuestionType($user);

Comment: I think you're right; I need to reduce the object graph to the correct answers before I start building the form. You mention passing in the User on construct. How would that help? I'm not having trouble getting the User id, but applying it as a filter. I'll update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: You are right.  I didn't read your original question closely enough.  You could iterate over $questions and just call setUser on each one before kicking off the form stuff.  But you really just want to join the answers when you query the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, the solution was to ensure the initial object graph was correct, rather than messing about with things once the FormBuilder was involved. In terms of getting a custom parameter into the setter, this seems to be the cleanest method:

[Symfony form: customize the setter that is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075054/symfony-form-customize-the-setter-that-is-called)

Answer (score 0):

After having a look in the Symfony code I saw that you can pass a options array into Symfonys FormBuilder (http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilderInterface.html#method_add). So you should be able to write this:

```
class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('answer', 'text', array($this->user));
    }
}
```

Please note I haven't tested this. In general the source code give you a good indication about the options. If a feature isn't implemented you can extend the class and implemented it yourself.