# A unique Symfony2 entity field related to several entities

Tags: php, symfony, entity, relationship

I need to get something very specific with Symfony2 and its entities.

The approach is as follows:

I have an entity called **Banner.php** and within a field called **link**.
I want this **link** field in the form, specifically will use SonataAdminBunlde, is a dropdown where you can select items that belong to two different entities, **Products.php** and **Blog.php**

Is this possible? Any idea how to do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?  You might want to try using the [Entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) along with using the options resolver in your form type class in the `public function setDefaultOptions(OptionResolverInterface $resolver){}` method.  You can require option fields there, and pass an array or collection of Products and Blogs when you build your form in the controller. `$this->createForm(new BannerType(), $banner, array('myLinks' => <array of Blogs and Products>));`

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have no code, I do not know how to start raising this issue. I've been looking at Entity field type ([class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#class)), but I see only you can link to an entity, not several. another question is how to save in database. an array field? two different fields?

Comment: You may want to just use a Choice Field then.  This means you'll need to handle fetching and validating the entity yourself on form submission, but you can easily handle that by pointing the field to a custom setter on your Banner entity.  `public function setLinkFromChoice($string){  // Determine the appropriate entity to fetch based on the string }`

Comment: Check this out about mapping and listeners http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075054/symfony-form-customize-the-setter-that-is-called

Comment: ok, thanks again, I will check it